# set field properties from a nested object in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a structure in the following format
I need to set the $User.Concerts.UserTitle a new property to a value $User.Concerts.User.Title

I have tried something like this  "User.Concerts.UserTitle" : "$User.Concerts.Users.Title" .
This sets the new property to an array instead of a string. How do I fix it?

```
{
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Title": "Title1",
    "User": [
        {
            "Id": "Userid2",
            "Title": "User Title1",
            "Concerts": [
                {
                    "Id": "Concert4",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid2",
                        "Title": "User Title2 Concert4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert1",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid2",
                        "Title": "User Title2 Concert1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "Userid1",
            "Title": "User Title1",
            "Concerts": [
                {
                    "Id": "Concert1",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert2",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert3",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You question is like "*I want to set value of 'A' to value of 'A'*" - this does not make any sense.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is not set value of A to value of A. The Concerts Object does not have a property UserTitle . As part of the query what I want is to set a new property UserTitle from Concerts.User.Title

Comment: The document does not have a property `Concerts.User.Title`. Please be more precise.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry. I meant it as Concerts.Users.Title. Basically i want a new property Concerts.UserTitle which gets from Concerts.Users.Title

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         User: {
            $map: {
               input: "$User",
               as: "user",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$user",
                     {
                        Concerts: {
                           $map: {
                              input: "$$user.Concerts",
                              as: "concert",
                              in: {
                                 $mergeObjects: [
                                    "$$concert",
                                    { UserTitle: "$$concert.Users.Title" }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xT67H-J73y2)